# Link AWS Resource to a CloudFormation stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudformation

I have a Cloudformation Stack launch an Amazon AMI instance.
Once this instance is started, I create an IAM user from a script (aws iam create-user --user-name blah).

My issue is that when I delete the Stack, this IAM is not a declared as its ressource and thus, not deleted at the same time.

Is there a way to link a resource to a CF stack ?

ps : I'm creating the IAM user from the linux instance because I want it part of a particular script, so I can't create it directly in the template as a Resources.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to link a resource to a CF stack ?

No, I don't believe so.

> I'm creating the IAM user from the linux instance because I want it
>   part of a particular script, so I can't create it directly in the
>   template as a Resources.

This is precisely what [EC2 IAM Roles](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html) are made for. Assign a server role (with appropriate permissions in IAM) via Cloudformation, and then from within the running instance, you can grab credentials from the metadata service. If you're using one of the officially-supported AWS SDKs, retrieval and rotation of credentials is handled transparently for you.

Comment: The script running in the instance is where I have my users list, not the other way around, where I define my users in the template/metadata and then push it to the instance.

Comment: FWIW, I solved my issue by executing some scripts to retrieve this user list, convert it to AWS JSON and add it to my template with sed.